# MeteorJS Session Object

Tags: javascript, meteor

I lately dived into MeteorJS.

I tried using the Session object once to make a simple todo list but when using methods such as `Session.get()` or `Session.set()` it doesn't work. When calling the Session object in the console by itself, it gives an error of `Session is not defined`

So is it still working and I am implementing it wrong or has the Session object been replaced with something else, perhaps the ReactiveVar. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that `session` isn't in your project, so start by running `meteor add session`

Then `Session` should be available in your console

Comment: Yeah, that was actually the case. Thank you so much for helping out! Also, I'm a beginner in Meteor and I am learning it because I have an application in mind that I want to create so wish me luck and thank you!

Comment: Good luck! I don't use Meteor anymore, but it was very fun when I did!